# Splitting file stream at second delimiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream, pipeline

I'm currently trying to stream a file, which looks a little bit like this:

```
Header
Title
Header
Title
...
```

The way I'm processing it is with a stream as such:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath, streamOpts)
  .pipe(split())
  .on('data', parseLine(data) => ...);
```

However this splits the file up at every line, and so `data` is just a single string of the next line. E.g.,

```
parseLine(line) => { console.log(data); } 
> "Header"
```

What I want is to split it up and somehow change `data` into an object, e.g.,

```
> "{ header: 'Header', title: 'Title' }"
```

Is there a way to do this? I guess it'd require getting two lines instead of one during the `pipe`, but I can't figure out how.

---

My current methodology is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const split = require('split');

var isHeaderLine = true;
var currentItem = {};
var items = [];

// Read the line from the stream
function parseFileLine(line) {
  if (isHeaderLine) {
    currentItem.header = line 
  } else {
    currentItem.title = line
    items.push(currentItem);
  }
} 

// Read the file as a stream
// Break it into processable lines
function parseFileLines(filePath) {
  const streamOpts = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
  };

  fs.createReadStream(filePath, streamOpts)
    .pipe(split())
    .on('data', parseLine);
}
```

However I don't feel this is the best way to do this. Is there a better way to split and pass two lines at once, preferably as an object or as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this using `Transform`:

```
function bufferSplitOnce(buffer, splitBuffer, nth) {
  const splitIdx = buffer.indexOf(buffer, splitBuffer, nth);

  return (splitIdx === -1)
    ? [buffer]
    : [buffer.slice(0, splitIdx), buffer.slice(splitIdx + 1)];
}

function bufferSplitN(buffer, splitBuffer, n) {
  const result = [buffer];
  let currentItem;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    result.push(...bufferSplitOnce(result.pop(), splitBuffer));
  }

  return result;
}


const streamToEntry = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    let chunkTail = chunk;

    while (chunkTail) {
      const splitChunk = bufferSplitN(chunkTail, '\n', 2);

      this.push({
        code: splitChunk[0],
        value: splitChunk[1],
      });

      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
      chunkTail = splitChunk[2];
    }
    callback();
  },
  readableObjectMode: true,
  writableObjectMode: true,
});

fs.createReadStream(filePath, streamOpts)
  .pipe(streamToEntry)
  .on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk);
  });
```